iPhone SE audio input simultaneously with computer data transfer
I have a wireless mic receiver with Lightning, USB-C, and 3.5mm TRS connectors. I'd like to be able to use this receiver while my iPhone SE is connected to a computer to use the OBS camera app. I've tried two Belkin adapters -- one with a 3.5mm jack and a lightning port and one with a two lightning ports -- and neither works.
I saw this question but it's not clear if that allows for data transfer between the phone and a computer while the audio is being received by the phone.

I found a solution which I will post here for the benefit of others. What is needed is a "Lightning to USB3 Camera Adaptor" which allows USB3 and Lightning devices to be connected simultaneously. So you can use the Apple Charger to power the iPad through the lightning port, and connect other devices via USB3.

Question: How can I achieve iPhone SE audio input simultaneously with computer data transfer?
List of Devices:

iPhone SE, model MX9K2LL/A, iOS Version 6.2
Wireless mic receiver as described above

Cables, Connectors, and Adapters:

Male lightning/male USB 2.0 cable (came with phone)
USB-C female/USB A male adapter

Computers (all can transfer data with phone when not connected through an adapter)

Acer C720-2013 running Lubuntu (lsb_release -a reports Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) and ifuse 1.1.4-git20181007.3b00243-1 with necessary prerequisities
LattePanda 3 Delta running Linux Mint (lsb_release -a reports Linux Mint 21.1) and ifuse 1.1.4-git20181007.3b00243-1 with necessary prerequisities
Mac Mini running OS 14.1 (23B74)

Microphone Info
AIKELA Wireless Lavalier Lapel Microphone
Microphone Info from Mac OS:
MFiIAP2Device:

  Product ID:                   0x1024
  Vendor ID:                    0x8087  (Intel Corporation)
  Version:                      1.00
  Serial Number:                0123456789ABCDEFG
  Speed:                        Up to 12 Mb/s
  Manufacturer:                 Generic
  Location ID:                  0x02312000 / 29
  Current Available (mA):       500
  Current Required (mA):        100
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

Similar output from lsusb -t -v -v on Linux:
|__ Port 5: Dev 6, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 8087:1024 Intel Corp. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5  /dev/bus/usb/002/006
    |__ Port 5: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
        ID 8087:1024 Intel Corp. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5  /dev/bus/usb/002/006
    |__ Port 5: Dev 6, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 8087:1024 Intel Corp. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5  /dev/bus/usb/002/006
    |__ Port 5: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 8087:1024 Intel Corp. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5  /dev/bus/usb/002/006

Copy-paste from the OBS camera web site:

If you've ever wanted to stream using your iPhone camera. We've got you covered. We've tried all the apps that let you do it over wifi, but they weren't fast enough, so we created an app that not only streams video & audio over Wi-Fi, but also over a low-latency wired USB connection to your Mac and PC using our OBS Studio plugin.

Failed Adapters
I used the Belkin adapter with the two lightning connectors (P-F8J198) and the adapter with a lighting connector and the 3.5 mm jack (P-F8J212), but neither allows simultaneous audio input and data transfer. I got ambiguous responses from Belkin's online chat about the capabilities of each device, but neither provided the functionality I want and I will be returning both. The two-lightning-connector version does not support data transfer; the 3.5 mm version dos not support audio input. edit: Subsequently I did try the adapter in the other question; it also doesn't allow a data connection.
What Does Work
Using OBS Wi-Fi kind of works -- the audio is garbled. This happens whether I'm using the built-in mic or the external mic, so it's hopefully not an issue with the mic and the OBS app. There is no garbling when using the built-in mic and OBS over USB. The mic works fine plugged directly into the phone.

Please explicate which device is connected to what interface, and using which cables. You mention three connection protocols, the OBS camera app on macOS (which does, what, exactly?) and two Belkin adapters. Also, please indicate which model of Mac, and running which version of macOS. More detail will help us to help you.

I've pasted a description of what OBS app does from their web site.

The receiver has the three connectors, and I have no preference as to which one is used so long as it works.

The desktop OBS application is available for Windows and Mac and can be compiled for Linux; I'm most likely going to use the last approach.

You do need to tell us what machine type and OS you are using. Without these crucial details, it is hard to assist. If you are in the middle of testing different CPUs and OSes, we need to know that up front. As written, your question, and the comments you’ve made, do little to explain the interconnection of these devices and software, the physical connections made, and TBH/ I’m not sure what you are actually trying  to accomplish.

Please let me know if you require further explication.

I've added as much detail as I have.

If I understand this correctly, you want to use your iPhone as a webcam for OBS while also using an external microphone on that iPhone? If yes, did you actually try to use the "Lightning to USB3 Camera Adaptor" mentioned in the other question?

Also, can you share the specific model of Wireless mic receiver you are using?

Does it work if (just for testing) you use WiFi to connect the OBS app on the phone to OBS on the computer?

Yes, @nohillside, you understand correctly. I've updated the question with the answers to your questions :)
